# Emacs: auto-fill-mode weird indentation behaviour

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am currently working on a major mode derived from auto-fill-mode where I need the text to show in a special indented way (it's a derivation of the [screenwriter.el](http://www.nongnu.org/screenwriter/) project), and I just got stuck with a peculiar behaviour of the auto-fill when there are multi line indentations:

(NOTE: use-hard-newlines is nil, and left-margin is 0):

How I expect it to work:

```
         DUDE           <-- here I insert a newline
     (sad)              <-- here I insert another newline 
Hello, look how good    <-- here I let the auto-fill-mode fill the text automatically
of a day it is!
```

But what happens is the following:

```
         DUDE           <-- here I insert a newline
     (sad)              <-- here I insert another newline 
Hello, look how good    <-- here I let the auto-fill-mode fill the text automatically
     of a day it is!
```

So basically the fill mode acts weirdly when there are multi indented paragraphs, indenting to the second line's left margin. I could not find anywhere how to avoid such a behaviour.

Even stranger, the following works just fine, indenting to the precedent line's margin.

```
         DUDE           <-- here I insert a newline
Hello, look how good    <-- here I let the auto-fill-mode fill the text automatically
of a day it is!
```

I wonder if it's just a bug or if there is a way to avoid this since it's quite annoying. Could anyone test if it works differently on other versions of emacs, or at least give me a hint on how to work around this? Thank you very much.

Emacs version: 24.3.1 on Windows

EDIT: I just checked and the same behaviour happens with use-hard-newlines on, so I'm oblivous to how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could customize the `adaptive-fill-mode` variable, which is what causes a prefix to be automatically determined when filling text. Set the variable to `nil` to disable that behaviour.

For details of how the prefix is worked out, see the `fill-context-prefix` function.

Comment: This is it. Now it is flawless. Thanks a bunch!